# Calling a method from another view controller for the Facebook API iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, uiviewcontroller

I have this method in an external view controller `APICallsViewController.m` that I want to call when a user touches a button from another view controller `MoreInfoCtrl.m`. How would I go about doing this?

I've made the import directive in `MorInfoViewController.m` `#import "APICallsViewController.h"`

This is for the Facebook API integrating it into an iOS app.

```
/*
 * Dialog: Request - send to a targeted friend.
 */
- (void)apiDialogRequestsSendTarget:(NSString *)friend {
    currentAPICall = kDialogRequestsSendToTarget;
    NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   @"Learn how to make your iOS apps social.",  @"message",
                                   friend, @"to",
                                   nil];

    HackbookAppDelegate *delegate = (HackbookAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [[delegate facebook] dialog:@"apprequests"
                      andParams:params
                    andDelegate:self];
    NSLog(@"Request - send to a targeted friend");

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `NSNotification` to add observer and then post notification on that button touch.

Comment: does that have to come from the app delegate or from the MoreInfoCtrl.m? thanks :)

Comment: from app delegate. add your observer when u start authorization and in fbdidlogedin postnotification to that method